# create function return : you do not have permission (SQL Server 2000)

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures, privileges

I'm trying to execute an SQL file who is doing this :

```
create function [finder].[fn_getName] (
...
)
```

I get this error :

Specified owner name 'finder' either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.

After some lines, the script is doing :

```
grant all on [finder].[fn_getName]
to myaccount
```

What `finder` means ?

If `finder` should be a `User` or a `Login`, do I have to create it before executing those lines ?

```
USE master
GO
sp_addlogin 'finder'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[finder]` is the schema name.

When you open a query page in SQL Server it usually has the `[master]` database selected, so you need to tell it which database to run your query on. You can do that by selecting the database in the 'Available Databases' drop-down list, or using the `USE` statement before executing other query statements.

E.g.

```
USE [finder]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_getName] (
...
)
GO

GRANT ALL ON [dbo].[fn_getName] TO myaccount
GO
```